# ¿Cómo crear correctamente las keys para traducir la plataforma en varios idiomas? Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto con Laravel 9.5X, específicamente estoy agregando etiquetas para, en un futuro, poder tener la plataforma en varios idiomas. La duda que tengo es la siguiente:

**Estaba intentando evitar** crear una key por cada botón, texto, label, etc mi idea, por ejemplo, era la siguiente:

```
[
'add' => 'Add :resource',
'new' => 'New :resource',
'delete' => 'Delete :resource' 
]
```

Entonces se puede crear un fichero `resources.php` en cada carpeta de idioma y puedes traducir los recursos, por ejemplo, Add category, New category y Delete category. El problema que acabo de notar es que, al menos en español, 'New' depende de la siguiente palabra, o sea, podría ser 'Nuevo' o 'Nueva' y eso significa que también podría pasar en otros idiomas con otras palabras (add, delete o otras) e incluso tener más de dos opciones.

Esto me lleva a pensar que lo mejor es crear una key por cada botón, label, etc, o sea,

En **/lang/en/buttons.php**

```
[
'add_category' => 'Add category',
'new_category' => 'New category',
'delete_category' => 'Delete category' 
]

En **/lang/es/buttons.php**

    [
    'add_category' => 'Agregar categoría',
    'new_category' => 'Nueva categoría',
    'delete_category' => 'Eliminar categoría' 
    ]
```

Si tienen experiencia con esto y me pueden aconsejar la mejor manera, lo agradecería mucho.